# How can I generate a number between 1 and 3 in a for loop?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1 and 3 for each snowflake, and the snowflake is moved down one pixel.

I am not sure how to do this because I'm really a beginner with `pygame`. I have tried it with a `for` loop before the `while` loop.

The code currently flickers different colors. Instead, it should just re-color the 'snowflakes'.

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine
pygame.init()

BLACK = [0, 0, 0]
WHITE = [255, 255, 255]
GREEN = [0, 255, 0]
RED = [255, 0, 0]
colourList = [BLACK, WHITE, GREEN, RED]
colour = random.choice(colourList)

# Set the height and width of the screen
SIZE = [400, 400]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snow Animation")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Create an empty list
snow_list = []

# Loop 100 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append((WHITE, [x, y]))


def recolour_snowflake(snowflake):
    color = [random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255)]
    return [color, snowflake[1]]


count = 0
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # If user clicked close
            done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    # change the color of snow flakes
    if count % 5 == 0:
        snow_list = list(map(recolour_snowflake, snow_list))
    count += 1

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Process each snow flake in the list
    for i in range(len(snow_list)):

        # Draw the snow flake
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, snow_list[i][0], snow_list[i][1], 3)

        # Move the snow flake down one pixel
        snow_list[i][1][0] += 1

        # If the snow flake has moved off the bottom of the screen
        if snow_list[i][1][0] > 400:
            # Reset it just above the top
            y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
            snow_list[i][1][1] = y
            # Give it a new x position
            x = random.randrange(0, 400)
            snow_list[i][1][0] = x

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: What do you mean it flickers different colors?

Comment: this whole code that i have should just return into a new colour. but it returns into different colors

Comment: You already know about `random.randrange`, so what are you missing exactly? Please provide a [mre]; this is too much code for such a simple question. Or is it actually more complicated?

Comment: Its actually complicated for me I couldn't do it. I don't meet the output that it wanted. I couldn't put it here cause its an animation/pygame

Comment: @wjandrea I think the code posted by the OP should work as is. All what is required is to pip install pygame.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the random module help you with generating random integers between 1 and 3 like this:

`import random`

`random.randint(1,4)`

Comment: # Loop 100 times and add a snow flake in a random x,y position
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append((WHITE, [x, y]))

this is my loop and i dont know how to write it. is it 

for i in range(random.randint(1,4)):

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random` to generate numbers in any particulate range. Here is the full code:

```py
import random

for j in range(420):
    print(random.randint(1,3))
```

This will print 420 lines with a number that is either 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Is it gonna be in this loop? 

for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(0, 400)
    y = random.randrange(0, 400)
    snow_list.append((WHITE, [x, y]))

Comment: Your code will generate 100 "x" coordinates in a range of 0-400 and 100 "y" coordinates in a range of 0-400.